# How can i create this type of user interface?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a tv remote application in that i have to create [image: app graphics] this type of user interface(ignore the red dashed line) i tried using a circle background that is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorGreyShade2"/>
            <padding
                android:bottom="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:left="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:right="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:top="@dimen/_40sdp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorGreyShade2"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorGreyShade2"/>

            <size
                android:width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_100sdp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorGreyShade1"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and using this as background of a layout and trying to adjust the navigation buttons in that but not able to achieve.
Can i use this image in an `ImageView` and detect user clicks from five button areas?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this from this. no need create drawable layer list. You can use imageview, textview and constraint layout.And this will also easy to implement all five button clicks.

bg_circle_fill_white.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/divider" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/black" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/_100sdp" />
</shape>
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_fill_white"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_previous_arrow"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_next_arrow"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/_20sdp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:text="OK"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_fill_white" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Image of UI you will get]